# ruby How I could print without leave newline space for each line?

Tags: ruby

ruby How I could  print without  leave newline space for each line

this is my file

```
name1;name2;name3

name4;name5;name6
```

I have this command

```
File.open("text2xycff.txt", "r") do  |fix|
  fix.readlines.each do |line|
    parts = line.chomp.split(';') 

input3= zero

 File.open('text2xyczzzz2.txt', 'a+') do |f| 
   f.puts  parts[0] ,  parts[1], parts[2]  ,input3
 end



end

end
```

this is my  output

```
name1

name2

name3

zero

name4 

name5

name6

zero
```

I need to output this

```
name1;name2;name3;zero

name4;name5;name6;zero
```

Please help me whit this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions.

The first one uses `puts` as you currently do:

```
File.open('yourfile.txt', 'a+') { |f|
    f.puts "#{parts[0]}#{parts[1]}#{parts[2]}#{input3}"
}
```

The second one uses `write` instead of `puts`:

```
File.open('yourfile.txt', 'a+') { |f| 
    f.write parts[0]
    f.write parts[1]
    f.write parts[2]
    f.write input3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more minimal approach is to just append something to each line:

```
File.open("text2xycff.txt", "r") do  |input|
  File.open('text2xyczzzz2.txt', 'a+') do |output| 
    input.readlines.each do |line|
      output.puts(line.chomp + ';zero')
    end
  end
end
```

Or if you want to actually parse things, which presents an opportunity for clean-up:

```
File.open("text2xycff.txt", "r") do  |input|
  File.open('text2xyczzzz2.txt', 'a+') do |output| 
    input.readlines.each do |line|
      parts = line.chomp.split(/;/)
      parts << 'zero'

      output.puts(parts.join(';'))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `puts` with comma-separated arguments, each one of them will be printed on a different line.

You can use ruby string interpolation here (http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html):

`f.puts "#{parts[0]};#{parts[1]};#{parts[3]};#{input3}"`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
File.open("test_io.txt", "r") do  |fix|
  fix.readlines.each do |line|
    File.open('new_file10.txt', 'a+') do |f|
      next if line == "\n"
      f.puts "#{line.chomp};zero"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why you're splitting the string by semicolon when you specified you wanted the below output. You would be better served just appending ";zero" to the end of the string rather than parsing an array.

name1;name2;name3;zero

name4;name5;name6;zero

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an `if` statement to check for the `zero` value.

Example:

```
arr = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "zero", "name4", "name5", "name6", "zero"];
arr.each { |x|
  if x != "zero" then
    print x
  else
    puts x
  end
}
```

Output:

```
name1name2name3zero
name4name5name6zero
```

`print` will print inline.

`puts` will print on a new line.

Just implement this logic in your code and you're good to go.